# Scope or initialization problem?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In an NSObject subclass declaration is an array:

```
    @interface theClass : NSObject {
        NSMutableArray *myArray;
    }
    ...

    @end
```

In the implementation's initializer:

```
    - (id)init
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            [myArray initWithCapacity:50];
        }

    return self;
    }
```

And in a method:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)theMethod:(NSArray *)someArray {
    ...
    ...

    [myArray addObject:anObject];
    ...

    return myArray;
}
```

Yet despite the class being instantiated in my controller, any number of messages to the method leave **myArray** without contents.

Comment: Class names should always start with capital letters by convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't allocated the array yet. Replace your `init` code with the following:

```
  - (id)init
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:50];
        }

    return self;
    }
```

Comment: Why is initWithCapacity sufficient to allow an array to be usable within a method?  And even so, is there reason to always use alloc first?

Comment: @terratactile: You have to allocate with `alloc` before you can do any initialization. That is, you must create the object before you can futz with it.